# slice pandas dataframe to get noncontiguous columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I have a `pandas.DataFrame`: `wordvecs_df`, with columns labeled `'word'`, `'count'`, `'v1'` through `'v50'` and `'norm1'` through `'norm50'` in that order.  I want to create a new pandas df with just the columns for `'word'`, `'count'` and `norm1-norm50`.

```
wordvecs_df.loc[:,"norm1":"norm50"]
```

gets me `norm1`-`norm50`, but if I try to put in word and count I get an IndexingError: Too many indexers.

I can't figure out how to get just the columns I want out of the dataframe.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can build up a list of column names like:

```
columns = ['word', 'count'] + ['norm%d' % i for i in range(1, 51)]
wordvecs_df.loc[:,columns]
```

Answer (score 3):

Stephen's answer works well, but in case the column names do not have nice format, the general solutions would be getting the column location, building the slice index, then accessing using iloc.

E.g.:

```
word_loc = wordvecs_df.columns.get_loc('word')
count_loc = wordvecs_df.columns.get_loc('count')
norm1_loc = wordvecs_df.columns.get_loc('norm1')
norm50_loc = wordvecs_df.columns.get_loc('norm50')

slice = np.r_[word_loc, count_loc, norm1_loc:norm50_loc]

df.iloc[:, slice]
```

Comment: Cool. I had never encountered [np.r_](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) before.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pd.concat:

```
pd.concat([df[['word','count']], df.loc[:,'norm1':'norm50']], 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Setup**
Let's use a smaller example

```
i = [0, 1]
c = range(1, 5)
wordvecs_df = pd.concat([
    pd.DataFrame(1, i, ['word', 'count']),
    pd.DataFrame(1, i, c).add_prefix('norm'),
    pd.DataFrame(1, i, c).add_prefix('v')
], axis=1)

wordvecs_df

   word  count  norm1  norm2  norm3  norm4  v1  v2  v3  v4
0     1      1      1      1      1      1   1   1   1   1
1     1      1      1      1      1      1   1   1   1   1
```

---

**Solution**
Use `pd.DataFrame.filter` to grab all things that look like `'norm'`

```
wordvecs_df.filter(regex='^norm\d\d?')

   norm1  norm2  norm3  norm4
0      1      1      1      1
1      1      1      1      1
```

We can tack it on to our other two columns via `pd.DataFrame.join` or `pd.concat`

```
wordvecs_df[['word', 'count']].join(
    wordvecs_df.filter(regex='^norm\d\d?'))

   word  count  norm1  norm2  norm3  norm4
0     1      1      1      1      1      1
1     1      1      1      1      1      1
```

Or

```
pd.concat([
    wordvecs_df[['word', 'count']],
    wordvecs_df.filter(regex='^norm\d\d?')
], axis=1)

   word  count  norm1  norm2  norm3  norm4
0     1      1      1      1      1      1
1     1      1      1      1      1      1
```